# Publishing EPSG:3857 raster in GeoServer

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, gdal

I have two sets of services, the first one is taking a satellite product and generating a GeoTIFF to be published in GeoServer via the second service.

The code for the first service is written in python and uses gdal bindings. The GDAL version is 3.1.0 and the code runs in a docker container which image is largely based on osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-latest.

When I try to publish the GeoTIFF in GeoServer I get an exception.

```
GeoTiffMetadata2CRSAdapter::createCoordinateSystem:Only Geographic & Projected Systems are supported.
```

After some investigation it seems to be down to the CRS it doesn't recognize. If I use 4326, then I have no problem publishing, if I use 3857 it fails.
If I gdalinfo the faulty GeoTIFF file this is what I get:

```
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]],
CONVERSION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator",
    METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
        ID["EPSG",1024]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8801]],
    PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8802]],
    PARAMETER["False easting",0,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8806]],
    PARAMETER["False northing",0,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8807]]],
CS[Cartesian,2],
    AXIS["easting (X)",east,
        ORDER[1],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
        ORDER[2],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
USAGE[
    SCOPE["unknown"],
    AREA["World - 85°S to 85°N"],
    BBOX[-85.06,-180,85.06,180]],
ID["EPSG",3857]]
```

I am using a GeoServer docker container with GeoServer 2.17, image is geosolutionsit/geoserver:cloudsi-2.17.x

How can I make the GeoServer publish my 3857 projected GeoTIFF? Do I need to add this "new" projection?

Comment: OK, after some research it appears GDAL >= 3 uses WKT2 which it seems GeoServer/GeoTools is struggling to parse.

Comment: Projection handling changed significantly at GDAL 3.x. Try dropping down to 2.4.2.